# Bad matrix inversion algorithm, or implemented incorrectly?

Tags: perl, matrix, inverse

Trying to implement matrix inversion in Perl myself, I found [An Efficient and Simple Algorithm for Matrix Inversion](http://www.irma-international.org/viewtitle/41011/) (only two pages of the article).

After my attempt to implement it in Perl, I see that it does not work.
I had spend **a lot** of time trying to find out what's wrong, so I concluded that

- either the algorithm is not correct
- I misinterpreted the algorithm
- my implementation is not correct

Before presenting the code, here's a debug session with an example from [Wikipedia: Inverse Matrix](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Matrix#Beispiele):

```
  DB<229> $m=[[2,5],[1,3]]

  DB<230> x invert($m)
pe[0] == 2
(pivot row 0) 2x2:
   2.000   2.500
   1.000   3.000
(pivot column 0) 2x2:
   2.000   2.500
  -0.500   3.000
(rest 0) 2x2:
   2.000   2.500
  -0.500   1.750
(pivot 0) 2x2:
   0.500   2.500
  -0.500   1.750
pe[1] == 1.75
(pivot row 1) 2x2:
   0.500   2.500
  -0.286   1.750
(pivot column 1) 2x2:
   0.500  -1.429
  -0.286   1.750
(rest 1) 2x2:
   0.908  -1.429
  -0.286   1.750
(pivot 1) 2x2:
   0.908  -1.429
  -0.286   0.571
0  1
1  3.5
  DB<231>
```

So here's the code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.026;
use strict;

# invert matrix
# An Efficient and Simple Algorithm for Matrix Inversion
# Ahmad Farooq, King Khalid University, Saudi Arabia
# Khan Hamid, National University of Computer and Emerging Sciences (NUCES),
# Pakistan
sub invert($)
{
    my $m = shift;          # matrix is an array of rows
    my ($pp, $det);
    my ($rp, $pe);
    my $n = scalar(@$m);

    for ($pp = 0, $det = 1.0; $pp < $n; ++$pp) {
        $rp = $m->[$pp];        # pivot row
        $pe = $rp->[$pp];       # pivot element
        print "pe[$pp] == $pe\n";
        last if ($pe == 0);      # Epsilon test?

        $det *= $pe;
        # calculate pivot row
        for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) {
            next if ($j == $pp);

            $rp->[$j] /= $pe;
        }

        pm($m, "pivot row $pp");
        # calculate pivot column
        for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
            next if ($i == $pp);

            $m->[$i]->[$pp] /= -$pe;
        }

        pm($m, "pivot column $pp");
        for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) {
            next if ($j == $pp);

            for (my ($i, $rj) = (0, $m->[$j]); $i < $n; ++$i) {
                next if ($i == $pp);

                $rj->[$i] += $rp->[$j] * $m->[$i]->[$pp];
            }
        }

        pm($m, "rest $pp");
        $rp->[$pp] = 1.0 / $pe;
        pm($m, "pivot $pp");
    }

    return ($pe != 0.0, $det);
}
```

The `pm()` function is just a "print matrix" for debugging purposes:

```
# print matrix
sub pm($;$)
{
    my ($m, $label) = @_;
    my $n = scalar(@$m);
    print "($label) " if ($label);
    print "${n}x${n}:\n";
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
        for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) {
            if (defined(my $v = $m->[$i]->[$j])) {
                printf('%8.3f', $v);
            } else {
                print ' ???????';
            }
        }

        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Any insights?

**Hint for Reproduction** (added 2019-08-28)

I had thought it was obvious, but just in case:
If you want to reproduce the output shown in the debug session, maybe just add these two lines at the end of the code:

```
my $m=[[2,5],[1,3]];                 # matrix to invert
print join(', ', invert($m)), "\n";  # invert $m, printing result
```

**Note** (added 2019-09-02):

The algorithm fails for the 3x3 matrix given in the Wikipedia article (`$m = [[1, 2, 0], [2, 4, 1], [2, 1, 0]]`), so real implementations should head towards the improved algorithm (that can select pivot elements outside the diagonal).

Comment: `use strict` is redundant after `use 5.026`, but you're missing `use warnings`.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a sample input matrix and inverted matrix along with the output of your script so we can see if there's a pattern to the wrongness.

Comment: @lordadmira: Can you tell what's not OK with the example given in the first code block?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really following that debugger output.  And unfortunately I haven't had time to study the algorithm.

Comment: I think the problem is in step #7 in the referred to paper. Note that there is a prime on `a[i,p]` but not on `a[p,j]`. So I guess you have to save the element of `a[p,j]` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: The question contains: "The pm() function is just a "print matrix" for debugging purposes:" Also as `i` and `j` can never be `p` in step 7 (the nested loop), I don't really understand what you are referring to.

Comment: @U.Windl Oh, I missed that about `pm`, I will delete that comment. Now about the second comment: Yes `i` and `j` can never be `p`, but `p` is still part of the formula. See my answer below. Please clarify what you don't understand

Comment: @HåkonHægland: In `$rj->[$i] += $rp->[$j] * $m->[$i]->[$pp]` `$rp` refers to the pivot row. As the pivot row is not touched in the nested loop, it's OK to use the "current" instead of the "previous" values I thought.

Answer (score 3):

**When in doubt, write tests.**

First, put your code into a module (`lib/My/Matrix.pm` or whatever you want to call it):

```
package My::Matrix; # this must match the file name

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( invert pm );

# your code here ...

1; # at end of module
```

There is a lot of documentation regarding writing modules, not sure if [perldoc perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) is a good starting point.

Now write a test - documentation is [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) (t/001-invert.t):

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

use Matrix qw(invert);

ok_invert( [[1,0], [0,1]], [[1,0], [0,1]], "unit matrix" );
# insert more matrices here    

done_testing;

sub ok_invert {
    my ($input, $output, $msg) = @_;

    invert( $output );
    is_deeply $input, $output, $msg
         or diag "got: ", explain $input, "expected: ", explain $output;
};
```

Run the test as `perl -Ilib t/001-invert.t` or `prove -Ilib t` if you want to run multiple tests.

You can now add simple corner cases to the test until the problem is isolated.

Of course, finding the correct inverse matrix by hand is tedious, so you may want to use multiplication instead. So the next steps to improve your code would be:

- make sure invert does not modify its input and returns the inverted matrix instead;

*Sidenote. It's generally a good idea to make sure a function [returns the desired value and does not modify its arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). It's not always possible but when it is, it saves a ton of debugging time.*

- implement multiplication;
- implement `is_unit_matrix` check;
- rewrite the test function as follows (the next snippet was not tested):

```
sub ok_invert {
    my ($input, $msg) = @_;
    my ($invert, $det) = invert( $input );
    ok is_unit_matrix( multiply( $invert, $input ) ), $msg
        or diag explain $invert, " is not the inverse of ", explain $input;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, the question was not how to write a module or how to test a module; I was wondering whether the algorithm presented is bad, or whether I misinterpreted the algorithm, or whether I don't see the obvious. Your answer doesn't really help me here.

Comment: @U.Windl So you are looking for a way to determine whether (an implementation of) an algorithm is good or bad. There are multiple ways to do so - testing, debugging, logging (which you do with `pm`), code inspection (which you seem to be asking for), pair programming, proving correctness manually or using a proof assistant, etc - but writing a quick test is _the path of least effort_. It is simple, it does not involve other people, it is easy to reproduce and it leaves behind a useful artifact.

Comment: As for my suggestion to use a module, of course it may be an overkill but you have self-contained code with well-defined behavior and modules are just natural habitat for that kind of things. And it is easier to write tests for a module than it is for a script.

Comment: Did you look at the paper? The algorithm was published in a magazine and there supposedly was a proof of correctness, but unfortunately that part is missing in the publicly available part. So I don't see the point of proving it's correctness; especially if I could, I would have written my own algorithm instead of relying to a published one.

Comment: @U.Windl There is an improved version by the same authors "An Efficient and Generic Algorithm for Matrix Inversion" which can be read online. In my experience implementing algorithms there is no way around test cases. Develop test cases, use a simple but working implementation as a reference and compare the results of the simple algorithm with the improved one. I did it this way implementing [LCS-BV](https://github.com/wollmers/LCS-BV) and tuning [Cistem stemmer](https://github.com/wollmers/Lingua-Stem-Cistem).

Comment: @Helmut Wollmersdorfer, It's already known that the test cases will Fail. The question is why are they failing. Dallaylean's doesn't help the OP at all.

Comment: Yes, testing is helpful to show that some software is *not working as designed*, but it cannot prove the correctness. As I already knew that the software is not providing the expected results, I absolutely see no sense in testing the software further.

Comment: @U.Windl I think you're right, I misinterpreted the question somewhat. Still if I was confronted with the problems you specify I would start out with writing tests and identifying corner cases and _then_ go into specific stages of the algorithm. My answer should have been a comment, if only SO supported such large comments.

Comment: OK, I verified that Wikipedia is correct using PostScript: `[2 5 1 3 0 0] matrix invertmatrix ==` prints `[3.0 -5.0 -1.0 2.0 0.0 0.0]`, so Wikipedia is correct (and my program is not).

Answer (score 2):

According to the referred to paper, step #7 should be computed with the old pivot row values, so the following seems to work for me:

```
sub invert($)
{
    my $m = shift;          # matrix is an array of rows
    my ($pp, $det);
    my ($rp, $pe);
    my $n = scalar(@$m);

    for ($pp = 0, $det = 1.0; $pp < $n; ++$pp) {
        $rp = $m->[$pp];        # pivot row
        $pe = $rp->[$pp];       # pivot element
        last if ($pe == 0);      # Epsilon test?

        $det *= $pe;
        # calculate pivot column
        for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
            next if ($i == $pp);
            $m->[$i][$pp] /= -$pe;
        }
        for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) { # row index
            next if ($j == $pp);
            for (my ($i, $rj) = (0, $m->[$j]); $i < $n; ++$i) {
                next if ($i == $pp);
                $rj->[$i] += $rp->[$i] * $m->[$j]->[$pp];
            }
        }
        # calculate pivot row
        for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) {
            next if ($j == $pp);
            $rp->[$j] /= $pe;
        }
        $rp->[$pp] = 1.0 / $pe;
    }

    return ($pe != 0.0, $det);
}
```

Fix required to match result in Wikipedia:

```
--- newinvert.pl~   2019-08-29 21:22:16.135160055 +0200
+++ newinvert.pl    2019-08-29 21:32:10.995144732 +0200
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@
             next if ($j == $pp);
             for (my ($i, $rj) = (0, $m->[$j]); $i < $n; ++$i) {
                 next if ($i == $pp);
-                $rj->[$i] += $rp->[$i] * $m->[$j]->[$pp];
+                $rj->[$i] += $rp->[$j] * $m->[$i]->[$pp];
             }
         }
         # calculate pivot row
```

Sample session (inluding my `pm()`):

```
> perl -d printmatrix.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.51
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(printmatrix.pl:20):  1;
  DB<1> require "./newinvert.pl" # this is ungly, forgive!
./newinvert.pl did not return a true value at (eval 6)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/perl5db.pl:738] line 2.

  DB<2> $m=[[2,5],[1,3]]
  DB<4> pm($m)
2x2:
   2.000   5.000
   1.000   3.000

  DB<5> x invert($m)
0  1
1  1
  DB<6> pm($m)
2x2:
   3.000  -5.000
  -1.000   2.000
```

Result of regression tests:

```
# https://github.com/wollmers/matrix-inverse-Farooq/blob/master/matrix_inversion_new.pl

$ perl matrix_inversion_new.pl
[...]
(invert_hakon 01_wiki input $A) 2x2:
   2.000   5.000
   1.000   3.000
(invert_hakon 01_wiki result $C) 2x2:
   3.000  -5.000
  -1.000   2.000
ok 10 - 01_wiki invert_hakon Ainv
ok 11 - 01_wiki invert_hakon det: 1
(invert_hakon 02_wiki input $A) 2x2:
   2.000   3.000
   1.000   2.000
(invert_hakon 02_wiki result $C) 2x2:
   2.000  -3.000
  -1.000   2.000
ok 12 - 02_wiki invert_hakon Ainv
ok 13 - 02_wiki invert_hakon det: 1
(invert_hakon 03_author_1 input $A) 3x3:
   1.000   1.000   3.000
   1.000   3.000  -3.000
  -2.000  -4.000  -4.000
(invert_hakon 03_author_1 result $C) 3x3:
   3.000   1.000   1.500
  -1.250  -0.250  -0.750
  -0.250  -0.250  -0.250
ok 14 - 03_author_1 invert_hakon Ainv
ok 15 - 03_author_1 invert_hakon det: -8
[...]
```

Comment: You are on the right track, but your version did not produce what the Wikipedia article says. However if you undo the exchange of indices `$i` and `$j`, the result matches Wikipedia. As it turns out you basically moved step 5 of the algorithm after step 7 to fix the problem. As comments have limited abilities, I'll hijack your answer to place the correction in there.

Comment: Ok, great! By the way I tested the code on a 3x3 matrix and it produced correct result, so I am not sure about exchanging those indices..

Comment: [I tested the original script on the 2x2 matrix](https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-matrix-invert-debug), and it gives the same result as you present for the modified script, can you see what the issue is?

Comment: I'm completely confused now: When I tried it the first time the matrix was mirrored on the diagonal, so I swapped the indexes you swapped back. The result was correct then, But now when I try to reproduce, the result is correct with your code, too! `$rj->[$i]` is a[i,j], and `$rp->[$i]` is a[p,i] (but that should be a[p,j]), while `$m->[$j]->[$pp]` is a[j,p]. To match Step 7, i and j should be swapped IMHO.

Comment: @U.Windl This original version is correct and passes my 3 testcases as I wrote in my answer. Look into my code at Github, where I do a sanity check on the testcases `is_deeply( matmult($A, $Ainv), $I )` where `$I` is the Identity matrix. The cases are also tested against different implementations: my `invert_corr()`, `invert_hakon()`, and `Math::Matrix->invert()`. Maybe you are confused, because `$A` is changed in place, and needs to be cloned `$Ainv = invert( matclone($A) )` if more than one `invert()` is done on the same array.

Comment: @U.Windl Based on this discussion, I suggest we rollback to the original version since it appears to be the correct one?

Comment: When the original `$rj->[$i] += $rp->[$j] * $m->[$i]->[$pp];` and your `$rj->[$i] += $rp->[$i] * $m->[$j]->[$pp];` produce the same results, what was your motivation for the change? IMHO the original version is what the algorithm says.

Answer (score 2):

The pseudocode in the original paper is not correct.

Steps I have done so far:

- inserted the pseudocode into the Perl source
- used the naming of the pseudocode
- test cases
- tested the test cases
- tested with `Math::Matrix` as a reference
- reviewed (many times)

At least I read the note in paper:

> Note that in step 7 of the following algorithm a'[i, p]
>   on the LHS means that the latest value of the pivot row
>   is to be used in the calculations.

This note is not really precise. After additional attempts I gave up, wanted to post my findings here, and read the answer of Håkon Hægland. Yes, his solution works and he earns the honor.

If the steps in the pseudocode are reordered it passes my 3 tests:

```
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4
Step 6
Step 7
Step 5
Step 8
Step 9
Step 10
```

Here is the version with pseudocode included and using the original naming:

```perl
sub invert_corr($) {
    my $A = shift;          # matrix is an array of rows
    my $n = scalar(@$A);

    # Step 1: Let p = 0, d = 1;
    my $p   = 0;
    my $det;
    # Step 2: p <= p +1
    for (my $pi = 0,$det = 1.0; $pi < $n; ++$pi) {
        $p = $pi;

        # Step 3: If a[p,p] == 0 then cannot calculate inverse, go to step 10.
        if ($A->[$p]->[$p] == 0) { last; }

        # Step 4: d <= d x a[p, p]
        $det = $det * $A->[$p]->[$p];

        # Step 6: Calculate the new elements of the pivot column by:
        #   a_new[i,p] <= -(a[i,p] / a[p,p]) where  i = 1 .. n, i != p
        STEP6: for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
            if ($i == $p) { next STEP6; }
            $A->[$i]->[$p] = -($A->[$i]->[$p] / $A->[$p]->[$p]);
        }

        # Step 7: Calculate the rest of the new elements by:
        #   a_new[i,j] <= a[i,j] + a[p,j] x a_new[i,p]
        #     where i = 1 .. n, j = 1 .. n, & i,j != p
        OUTER7: for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
            if ($i == $p) { next OUTER7; }
            INNER7: for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) {
                if ($j == $p) { next INNER7; }
                # Note that in step 7 of the following algorithm a'[i, p]
                # on the LHS means that the latest value of the pivot row
                # is to be used in the calculations.
                $A->[$i]->[$j] = $A->[$i]->[$j] + $A->[$p]->[$j] * $A->[$i]->[$p];
            }
        }

        # Step 5: Calculate the new elements of the pivot row by:
        #   a_new[p,j] <= a[p,j] / a[p,p] where  j = 1 .. n, j != p
        STEP5: for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) {
            # next if ($j == $p);
            if ($j == $p) { next STEP5; }
            $A->[$p]->[$j] = $A->[$p]->[$j] / $A->[$p]->[$p];
        }

        # Step 8: Calculate the new value of the current pivot location:
        #   a_new[p,p] <= 1 / a_new[p,p]
        $A->[$p]->[$p] = 1.0 / $A->[$p]->[$p];

        # Step 9: If p < n go to step 2 (n the dimension of the matrix A).
    }

    # Step 10: Stop. If inverse exists, A contains the inverse and d is the determinant.
    if ($A->[$p]->[$p] != 0.0) {
        return ($A->[$p]->[$p] != 0.0, $det, $A);
    }
    return ($A->[$p]->[$p] != 0.0);
}
```

The complete code including tests is available on [github](https://github.com/wollmers/matrix-inverse-Farooq/blob/master/matrix_inversion_new.pl), maybe useful for debugging.

Comment: So can we agree that the description of the algorithm is at least "poor"?

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, the description is poor and potentially misleading. This applies in my experience to 50% of the scientific papers written by mathematicians. Without code in a popular language (or unambiguous pseudocode) it's hard to verify the claims in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems when implementing a mathematical formula like (actually from **Step 5**)
[image]
in a loop is: When will the "new" `a'` become the "old" `a`?
Before the next step, before the next assignment, or before the next loop iteration?

In a mathematical sense `a'` and `a` are different variables all the time, but in procedural programming languages the memory address for `a` is reused at some time.

So the assignments from **Step 5** need to be delayed after **Step 7** ([image]), it seems.

As a computer scientist I had always felt that mathematical algorithms are described in a somewhat imprecise way. Maybe that's exactly the reason why programming languages were invented ;-)